# Pass Parameters To GcmTaskService

Tags: android, service, parameters, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement a service using the GcmTaskService.
This is my code in the main activity to call the service called Myservice.

```
OneoffTask myTask = new OneoffTask.Builder()
            .setService(MyService.class)
            .setExecutionWindow(0, 10)
            .setTag("test-upload")
            .build();

    GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this).schedule(myTask);
```

This is the MyService class.

```
    public class MyService extends GcmTaskService {

    @Override
    public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
        Log.i("onRunTask: ", taskParams.getTag() + "");
        return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_RESCHEDULE;
    }
}
```

What i want to know is how do i pass parameters to this service?

Comment: Can you specify what kind of parameters you'd want to pass in to the onRunTask? `TaskParams` has a getTag() method that refers to the tag of your task, if that is what you need to track. Please refer [here](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/67) and to [a sample GCMTaskService](https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/master/samples/android/gcm-demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/service/TaskSchedulerService.java).

Comment: I need the task to send data to a server when the internet connectivity is back so i need to pass an array list containing Strings to this task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/TaskParams

TaskParams has a getExtras() which returns a bundle for you to use.  This should be populated by the call to setExtras() on your TaskBuilder.

Comment: Haven't personally tried this, but happened upon this question while looking up something else.  Seems like this should be the answer...